# Collecting attendees onto Event Object

Tags: apex, trigger, relationships, event

I want to collect the Attendees of events on to a custom text field on the Event object.
I am running into issues collecting the names via the Event Relation.

```
trigger EventAttendeeCollector2 on Event (after insert, after update) {

For (Event EVT:trigger.new){


    List <eventRelation> Erelates =[select RelationId from eventRelation where eventID=: EVT.id]; 

    system.debug('ERELATES______________________________________'+ERELATES);


    Set<Id> erelateSet = (new Map<Id,SObject>(Erelates )).keySet();
    system.debug('erelateSet================================='+erelates);


    List <user> Users =[select name from User where id IN: erelateSet ];

    system.debug('userslist====================='+Users);

}
```

}

Query for Users returns no users though I see Users' ids in the Set I am querying against. 
How come? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line
`Set<Id> erelateSet = (new Map<Id,SObject>(Erelates )).keySet();`
populates the ID's of the EventRelation records into the set and not the RelationId.

You would need to loop over the list and populate the set.

```
Set<Id> erelateSet = new Set<Id>();
for(EventRelation evtRel : Erelates){
    erelateSet.add(evtRel.RelationId);
}
```

Comment: I need a map, don't I, to assign the collected users to the Right WhatId...

Comment: actually a double map? b/c whatid to eventRelation, then whatId to User